# Need help rounding results

Tags: sql-server

i have the following report,

```
    select E.FullName, EL.DateTimeStart, EL.DateTimeStop, E.EmployeeStatusCode, EL.ExtraMinutes,
       Sum(El.ShiftTime /60.0 + (ExtraMinutes / 60.0)) as TotalHoursWorked
FROM       dbo.Employee AS E
INNER JOIN dbo.employeelog AS EL 
ON         E.EmployeeKey = EL.EmployeeKey   
where      EL.DateTimeStart BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate +1)and EmployeeStatusCode = @EmployeeStatusCode
GROUP BY   FullName, EL.DateTimeStart, EL.DateTimeStop, E.EmployeeStatusCode, EL.ExtraMinutes
having     Sum(El.ShiftTime /60.0 + (ExtraMinutes / 60.0)) > 0
ORDER BY   FullName
```

this returns peoples working hours for each day for a chosen date range and works fine:

```
 2017-04-15 13:53:02.040    2017-04-15 14:03:41.177 C   0   0.166666
 2017-04-15 14:03:41.177    2017-04-15 14:12:00.303 C   0   0.150000
 2017-04-15 14:16:29.610    2017-04-15 22:22:47.953 C   -30 7.600000
 2017-06-08 06:30:00.000    2017-06-08 12:08:54.210 C   -30 5.133333
 2017-06-08 12:08:54.210    2017-06-08 12:15:53.850 C   0   0.116666
 2017-06-08 12:15:53.850    2017-06-08 14:37:10.040 C   0   2.366666
```

i have only now come into an issue as i am trying to round the results.

i tried using `Round()/0.5, 0) *0.5`, but the problem there was that is was rounding the daily times for each employee.

```
2017-04-15 13:53:02.040 2017-04-15 14:03:41.177 C   0   0.000000
2017-04-15 14:03:41.177 2017-04-15 14:12:00.303 C   0   0.000000
2017-04-15 14:16:29.610 2017-04-15 22:22:47.953 C   -30 7.500000
2017-06-08 06:30:00.000 2017-06-08 12:08:54.210 C   -30 5.000000
2017-06-08 12:08:54.210 2017-06-08 12:15:53.850 C   0   0.000000
2017-06-08 12:15:53.850 2017-06-08 14:37:10.040 C   0   2.500000
```

the way our system is setup currently is that employees working times are rounded at the end of the week `Round(the sum of all the days /0.5, 0)* 0.5`, and not after everyday, so i only need to round the sum, or their weekly total hours. sorry if it is confusing, i am confusing myself a lot and i need some help. :P

i write my reports in ms SQL server management studio, and finalize them in report builder. 
much appreciated nick

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to add this comment to the answer section, but apparently my points are not high enough that the sight allows me to make comments  :-)

Here is my comment/question, it looks like you are listing out times for every employee and day.  Are you looking to add a "Total for the week" row that you would round?  or are you looking to figure out the weekly rounding amount and apply it to each day (this way sounds complicated)? Please explain.

Comment: hey yes, as assumed i want to add all their times for 1 week, or whatever dates are wanted using the parameter, and round that total. and i would just like to know the best way of approaching this. thanks

Comment: how i have it now is that in report builder i total all the hours per day, and this is the value i want to get and round. thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 0):

Are you round the TotalHoursWorked? or did I misunderstand?  To round to the nearest thousands.

```
select E.FullName, EL.DateTimeStart, EL.DateTimeStop, E.EmployeeStatusCode, EL.ExtraMinutes,
       round(Sum(El.ShiftTime /60.0 + (ExtraMinutes / 60.0)),3) as TotalHoursWorked
FROM       dbo.Employee AS E
INNER JOIN dbo.employeelog AS EL 
ON         E.EmployeeKey = EL.EmployeeKey   
where      EL.DateTimeStart BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate +1)and EmployeeStatusCode = @EmployeeStatusCode
GROUP BY   FullName, EL.DateTimeStart, EL.DateTimeStop, E.EmployeeStatusCode, EL.ExtraMinutes
having     Sum(El.ShiftTime /60.0 + (ExtraMinutes / 60.0)) > 0
ORDER BY   FullName
```

Comment: no mate, these results i gave shows employees daily hours, how i have it now is that in report builder i total all the hours per day, and this is the value i want to get and round. thanks for any help you can give